# tempnam() error in when display images using tcpdf, php 7 and drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, tcpdf

We are getting below error when generating pdf file using tcpdf in drupal 7.

```
Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in TCPDF_STATIC::getObjFilename() (line 296 of /var/www/html/sites/all/libraries/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php).
```

When we commenting the below code, this error will disappear

```
$path = 'sites/default/files/'.$user->mail.'/'.$sign_file;
   $tcpdf->Image($path,145, 102.75, 40, 15, $sign_filetype , '', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

File permissions of this file is

```
-rw-rw---- 1 apache apache 5917 Mar  4 23:10 sign.png
```

Version details are TCPDF module - 7.x-1.0-beta1 and php    7.2.27. Thanks in advance for any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: This seems to be not an error but actually a feature according to [this user comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#120451)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding the path of temp directory in php.ini file. Eg:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem today, I was able to resolve it without going to the php.ini

in **tcpdf_lib\config\tcpdf_config.php**

```
define ('K_PATH_CACHE', '/mypath/tcpdf_lib/cache');
```

Was set, but there was no cache directory. Creating one with appropriate permissions correct the PHP notice.